# How to use the local json data in Morris.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, morris.js

I'm trying to plot the morris line dynamically based on the local data file - sales.php (in json format):

```
[
  { year: '2008', value: 20 },
  { year: '2009', value: 10 },
  { year: '2010', value: 5 },
  { year: '2011', value: 5 },
  { year: '2012', value: 20 }
]
```

You can see my HTML code below. But there is no graph at page and I see just the blank one. Also, there is no error in java console (except warning about async). The result will be the same if I change the script position to 'head' or 'body'.

May this problem caused by an ajax query syntax or (may be) data structure in sales.php?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="line-example"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "sales.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (json) {
            Morris.Line({
                element: 'line-example',
                data: $.parseJSON(json),
                xkey: 'year',
                ykeys: ['value'],
                labels: ['Value']
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your sales.php file ?

Comment: there is no any code, this file consist of pure data in the json format. See the screen of sales.php content https://gyazo.com/380d14fe8bd6a258c3355d69e4eef014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your `sales.php` to `sales.json`. If you name your file with the php extension, your server will try to interpret your file but there's no php tag in your file.

And write a proper json object:

```
{
  "sales": [
      { "year": "2008", "value": 20 },
      { "year": "2009", "value": 10 },
      { "year": "2010", "value": 5 },
      { "year": "2011", "value": 5 },
      { "year": "2012", "value": 20 }
  ]
}
```

Change the `data` of your Morris:

```
data: json.sales
```

Finally, change the `url` of your ajax:

```
url: "sales.json"
```

Comment: thnx, I replaced the extension and provide these corrections. After that java console show [error: "jquery.js:539   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"](https://gyazo.com/c039b523f04fdfcf08fc19c6a12a7b90). 
As I understand, this error caused by some problem with the data format.

Comment: I updated my answer. You don't need to parse the json returned because it was not stringified. @Evgeny